# Deriving the shape of a suspension bridge with a heavy load

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

You can use the Euler Lagrange equation to show how the shape of a suspended cable with no load is simply a catenary. However, if you suspend a much heavier load (i.e. a bridge) with the cable, the cable forms a parabolic shape. Does anyone know how to show this fact using the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: Why do you need/want EL equation for the analysis? Couldn't you accomplish the same task more easily using arc length parametrization (which would show $y'\propto x$)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just confused as to why the E-L approach doesn't work. It should work, since we're simply trying to minimize the potential energy of the system.

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this. It seems minimizing potential $\int fydx$, where $f$ is constant force density, with constrained length, $\int \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$ does not lead to a parabola. Why?